# beautifulsoup не видит сlass при парсинге

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

float = soup.find('div', class_='text-muted text-center').get_text()

[image: Это float или цифирки под скинами на оружие, на сайте:Bitskins]

Не видит этот класс, ничего не хочет с ним делать. Div выше - видит, ниже - тоже, а этот не хочет...
PS Использую request и bs4

Comment: а просто class_='text-muted' не пробовали?

Comment: при text_muted выходит общая информация с сайта, а не то, что нужно, но спасибо, не знал что так можно)

Comment: попробовал для уточнения так, но так же мимо
'soup': item.find('div', {"style": 'position: relative; margin-top: -35px; font-size: 0.9em;',"class": 'text-muted'})

Comment: дайте адрес сайта?

Comment: https://bitskins.com/

Comment: Вот это я пытаюсь спарсить, https://prnt.sc/zbskf6 , там есть Тоже это значение, но в другом блоке https://prnt.sc/zbsp6x , мне нужно именно первое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного не там ищете. Попробуйте:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://bitskins.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

все плашки с экипировкой:

```
panels = soup.find_all('div', class_='item-featured')
```

среди них заголовок и износ:

```
for p in panels:
    # заголовок
    title = p.find('div', class_='item-title').text.replace('★', '').strip()
    # общий и относительный износ
    wear = p.find('span', class_='unwrappable-float-pointer')
    # у некоторых износ не указан, нужна проверка
    if wear:
        wear = wear.text.split(',')
    else:
        wear = '', ''
        
    print(f'{title:45} {wear[0]:15} {wear[1]}')
```

выводит:

```
Specialist Gloves | Foundation                0.31258446      0.16258446
AK-47 | The Empress                           0.16022542      0.01022542
USP-S | Neo-Noir                              0.06788366      0.06788366

...

Hand Wraps | Arboreal                         0.19734952      0.04734952
Falchion Knife | Night                        0.16817449      0.01817449
Cologne 2016 Cobblestone Souvenir Package
```

Comment: Большое спасибо